# Finding size of array at run time

Tags: c++, c, arrays, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the sizeof(a pointer pointing to an array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

i am passing an array to a function. is there is any way of finding the size of array in that function.

i don't think that sizeof function works as only pointer to first element of the array is passed to the function.

```
sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])
```

i don't think that the above code works. is there any other way...

Thanks...

Comment: Pass the size as an additional parameter unless you want to use templates.

Answer (score 4):

Using raw arrays, there's no simple or reliable way to find its size once it is passed as a pointer to a function.  (I don't count reading the debug information from the binary as simple, for example.)

In C++, you should probably be using a `std::vector<YourType>` and then you can find out easily.

In C, you have to ensure you pass the size as well as the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

If your c++ tag is serious, you can use `std::vector` since it keeps the size information `vec.size()`. Otherwise you need to pass the size to the function, or have a structure/class keep array and size together.

Comment: `std::array` is a template type (templated on the array size); `std::vector` is resizable at runtime. I suspect that if OP is at a level where these kinds of questions need to be asked, the extra flexibility will be appreciated.

Comment: He meant `std::vector`. `std::array` can be used, when the size is known at the compile time.

Comment: true, `std::vector` will be easier to use

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a pointer to the first element then no, there is no way to know the size of the array. If you really need to know the size, you have a few options;

- Terminate the array with a value that does not exist in normal data (an example is a \0 as C uses to terminate strings or NULL in a pointer array)
- Pass the length of the array around with the array.
- Change to a datatype that knows about size, like std::vector (not an option in C, but you also tagged C++)
- Create your own struct that can contain size+array pointer and pass that around.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. That why all sensible functions from the C Standard Library pass a pair of `(pointer, size)` as parameters. In C++ the convention is to pass two pointers, `(start, end)` instead, which is almost equivalent.